# AuthenticationManager called in case of certificate based client

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

Which AuthenticationManager is invoked by spring when using certificate based client authentication? Currently I am using PamAuthentication and I need to use a certificate based authentication. I see that the org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService is not invoked anymore. Which implementation is invoked in case of certificate based authentication?

Answer (score 0):

When using a certificate based authentication, `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` will be in charge of authenticating the client. First of all, the filter extracts the client principal through `X509AuthenticationFilter`. After that, an authentication token is created using the cert CN as a principal and the cert DN as a credentials. The `AuthenticationManager` implementation that will perform the authentication of that token is `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider`, which will use your implementation of `UserDetailsService` to authenticate the client.

You can enable certificate authentication by adding it to the HttpConfigurer, and configure your own implementation of `UserDetailsService`.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .x509()
        .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)")
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
            if(user.isPresent()){
                return new User(username, userCredentials, new Role("ROLE_USER"));
            }
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User" + username + "does not exist");
        }
    };
}
```

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security) you have an example of x509 certificate authentication.

Comment: Hi lsantamaria, the above userDetailsService() is invoked only once on starting the server, it is not invoked for every http request(for login), how do I get it to be invoked every time the login request is made.

Comment: With the configuration above, using Spring boot, it is invoked on every request. Could you provide more details about your configuration?

Comment: We already have in place a provider for username/password (Oauth type is password) and we need to provide an additional provider for client_credentials.